# Image background of a layout is not acroos screen, but only half?

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, android-linearlayout

I have a layout, with a image, button and a textview. When I set image as backgroung, this background image is only Half of screen, and the rest is black. This method is good on other layout where i have bunch of stuff, but here it is only on half of the screen. How can i make this right ??

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/bonbon" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<cro.perger.bonbon.MyTextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:text="Stanje aktiviranih paketa" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Provjeri stanje" 
    android:id="@+id/provjeriStanje" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:text=" " 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: instead of  android:src="@drawable/bonbon" try  android:background="@drawable/bonbon"

Comment: no, bonbon is only image, not background .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ScrollView as a root component, it has it's height defined as "wrap_content". This is, most likely, the cause of your issue. Try this version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:background="@drawable/background" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/bonbon" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<cro.perger.bonbon.MyTextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:text="Stanje aktiviranih paketa" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Provjeri stanje" 
    android:id="@+id/provjeriStanje" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:text=" " 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview is wrapping the content which probably isn't filling the whole screen.

Change android:layout_height="wrap_content" to fill_parent in the scrollview tag.

Answer (score 0):

Now Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:background="@drawable/Path"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/Path"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Provjeri stanje"
            android:id="@+id/provjeriStanje" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text=" " android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```